# How to position a div element on the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this div to be all the way to the right side of the screen. here is the html:

```
  <html>
 <head>
  title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
 </head>
  <h1> </h1>
 <body>

<div id="bannerR">
 <a href="yahoo.com" target=_blank>
 <img src="yahoo.com" border=0></a>
</div>
```

and here is the style.css

```
        #header{background-color: #fff; width: 1000px; position: relative; }

     #bannerL{ position: relative; top: 500px; left: 500px; }
      #bannerR{ position: relative; float: right; }



        body    {
     background-image: url("beach.gif");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     margin-top:100px;
     margin-right:180px;
     margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:200px;
```

}

please help, Im very new at code and bought a book but that hasnt helped. I have spent few hours trying to get this and to no avail.

Comment: Is that your entire HTML file? Is the stylesheet linked to the HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KV4RM/ is this your output?

Comment: Why do you have a margin on your `body` tag? I'm guessing if you remove `margin-right:180px` your `#bannerR` will be all the way to the right.

Comment: margin on body tag is for the picture I have in background. Do you still suggest I try deleteding     margin-right:180px?

Comment: Yes. Use `background-position` for the image. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: If I want to have a banenr all the way on the left, I would have to delete Margin-left:200px?

Comment: Yes. You should delete all the margins on the `body` styles.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your need of `floats` on both the left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `body` styles contain `margin-right:180px`. Because of that the `#bannerR` will never float all the way to the right. Remove that style and it'll work. Here is some code:

`body
{
background-image: url("beach.gif");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}`

Here's a fiddle to show it in proof: http://jsfiddle.net/rzKaz/1/

Comment: Also, your HTML is missing some quote marks around `"_blank"` and `border="0"`

Comment: Okay, thank you. how would I center this? #bannerL{ position: relative; top: 500px; left: 500px; }    

Also, do you know any good sites to learn so i don't have to keep asking questions?

Comment: and what do i do now about the width and height?

Comment: Can you mark this answer as approved, as it answers your original question? For the other question, centering: `#banner {position:relative, margin:auto auto;}` In order for it to work though, you need to have content in the `div` or set a `height` and `width`.

Comment: Other site (there may be others, but a good start): http://www.w3schools.com/css/ or http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: i clciked the check mark, thank you for helping me with muktiple questions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DIV isn't contained within an element with restricted space (doesn't span the entire width of the page)

Comment: I edited the posy, What is this restircted space you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link the css file to the HTML so the browser knows what css files you are using.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- YOUR HTML -->
  </body>
</html>
```